# Alterar cor do fundo do título de uma Dialog

Tags: java, android, xml

Tenho a seguinte caixa de diálogo:

[image: Dialog]

A parte verde foi montada com um `LinearLayout`, porém o atributo `android:background="#77FF77"` não alterou a cor da barra de título.

Java da Dialog:

```
public void ver_log(View v){
   DialogLog();
}

private void DialogLog(){
    final Dialog dialogLog = new Dialog(this);
    dialogLog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_log);

    dialogLog.setTitle("CÁLCULOS");

    final Button btnFechar = (Button) dialogLog.findViewById(R.id.btn_fechar);
    final Button btnCopiar = (Button) dialogLog.findViewById(R.id.btn_copiar);

    btnFechar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialogLog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    btnCopiar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Ação de copiar
        }
    });

    dialogLog.show();
}
```

XML da Dialog:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    style="@style/Dialogs" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/relatorio"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <Button
            style="@style/BotoesDialogs"
            android:id="@+id/btn_fechar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/fechar" />
        <Button
            style="@style/BotoesDialogs"
            android:id="@+id/btn_copiar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/copiar" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Como posso alterar essa parte?
Seria possível também alterar a cor do título "CÁLCULOS" e essa barra azul embaixo?

Comment: Você tem duas maneiras, ou sobreescreve os **style's** do `Dialog` no seu tema. Ou remove o título (usando o `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)` no `onCreate`, antes de qualquer coisa) e cria um título customizado para o `Dialog`, dentro do layout do conteúdo do seu `Dialog`.

Comment: Apesar de não responder sua pergunta, talvez isso lhe ajude:  https://github.com/inmite/android-styled-dialogs

Comment: Funcionou, @Wakim. utilizei o `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)` colocando logo acima da definição do layout da `Dialog`. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem duas maneiras:

Ou sobrescreve os style's do `Dialog` de todo app no seu tema.

Ou remove o título, usando o [`Dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#requestWindowFeature(int)) no `onCreate`, **antes de qualquer coisa**. E cria um título customizado para o `Dialog`, dentro do layout do conteúdo do seu `Dialog`